# Check date field every night and update field

Tags: apex, trigger, automation

I would like some help about creating some automation which would run at midnight:
On a custom object, (Resource Allocation) There is a custom field (Allocation_Status__c) which is a picklist and can have 3 values:

- Active
- Closed
- Closed – Early Termination

If a Contractor is terminated or leaves earlier than the scheduled End Date of their contract – then the Allocation_Status__c is manually amended to ‘Closed – Early Termination’ by a user.

But if the Allocation naturally rolls over (End_Date__c < Today()), I want to update the Allocation_Status__c field to be ‘Closed’ but not touching those records which have ‘Closed – Early Termination’ as their Picklist in Allocation_Status__c.

How do I go about doing this? Would I need to write/schedule an Apex Job?

Comment: Yes, you need a scheduled job. I recommend you try writing one and come back with more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Could probably do this with a time-based workflow.. filter the status on the enter criteria, and set the status to update to "Closed" say, an hour after the close date.

Answer (score 0):

[here's the docs for batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) 
and [here's the docs for scheduling apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

You basically just want to query for any Allocations where `End_Date__c < TODAY AND Allocation_status__c != 'Closed' AND Allocation_status__c != 'Closed – Early Termination'` in your batch's Start method.

Iterate through all those records and just set Allocation_Status__c to 'Closed' then update the list.